# LWIP: Monitor and close a TCP connection with Netconn API

Tags: c, tcp, lwip

I am using Lwip 2.1.2 with FreeRtos v10.0.0 and the Netconn API.
I am trying to find a way to gracefully close a Netconn connection and try to reconnect in case of a communication issue.

Currently, to identify a communication issue, I try to do a

> netconn_write()

and in case this method returns an error I try to

> netconn_close()

and

> netconn_delete()

the netconn connection.

To simulate a TCP connection I use Netcat in Linux (Running on my host PC) and my Embedded Device is connected with an Ethernet cable to my PC.
By the time I have a connection and receive data on the PC, I try to simulate a communication interruption by just killing the Netcat connection (Ctrl+c). However, I get the following errors:

- **netconn_close(netconn)** returns error: -11 (ERR_CONN = Not connected)
- **netconn_delete(netconn)** returns error: -5 (ERR_INPROGRESS = Operation in progress)

A simplified version of my code:

```cpp
    void FooMethod()
    {
      netconn* tcpListenNetconn;
      netconn* connection;
    
      tcpListenNetconn = netconn_new(NETCONN_TCP);
      netconn_bind(tcpListenNetconn, IP4_ADDR_ANY, TCP_PORT);
      netconn_listen(tcpListenNetconn);
      netconn_accept(tcpListenNetconn, &connection);
    
      uint8_t buffer = 0x65;
    
      while(1)
      {
         err_t error = netconn_write(connection , &buffer , 1, NETCONN_COPY);
         if (error != ERR_OK)
         {
             netconn_close(connection);
             netconn_delete(connection);
             break;
         }
      }
    }
```

**Update**

I realized that if I kill netcat on the host machine, the TCP connection will be closed in the background, that's why I get the error messages from

> netconn_close()

and

> netconn_delete()

While I could ignore the closing errors, my next problem was when I was trying to re-connect I was getting an error from

**netconn_bind()**: -8 (ERR_USE, Address in use)

But this is because I try to reconnect to the same port. Apparently Netconn API doesn't provide options for reusing an IP Address or a Port, so the probably the Socket API has to be used.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem (how to detect a connection is broken, how to avoid "address in use"). Did you find a good solution?

Comment: Not really, as I mention the netconn API doesn't provide option for address reuse, so I ended up using the sockets API, which works fine.